# HTML: Cant get to show on browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML and have come across some difficulty. I am not able get the other texts to appear on the page [The Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rYNt.png). Could use help, thanks.
Using: Bluefish Editor
Using Crome to run page

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Temperature</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function showTime() {
        var tempByHour = new Array();
        tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
        tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
        tempByHour[2] = 63;
        tempByHour[3] = 65;
        tempByHour[4] = 62;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
          var id = "temp" + i;
          var li = document.getElementById(id);

          if (i == 0) {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon is " + theTemp;
          } else {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + i + "was" + theTemp;
          }
        }

        window.onload = showTime
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Temperature</h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="temp0"></li>
    <li id="temp1"></li>
    <li id="temp2"></li>
    <li id="temp3"></li>
    <li id="temp4"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: solved your issue or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sometimes you need to check the console, if there any errors. It seems you forgot to put the `}` at the end of the `showTime` function. And also change you for loop like this  `for (var i = 0; i < tempByHour.length; i++) { ... }` to cover the whole length of your `tempByHour` array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Temperature</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function showTime() {
        var tempByHour = new Array();
        tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
        tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
        tempByHour[2] = 63;
        tempByHour[3] = 65;
        tempByHour[4] = 62;

        for (var i = 0; i < tempByHour.length; i++) {
          var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
          var id = "temp" + i;
          var li = document.getElementById(id);

          if (i == 0) {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon is " + theTemp;
          } else {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + i + " was " + theTemp;
          }
        }
    }

        window.onload = showTime
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Temperature</h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="temp0"></li>
    <li id="temp1"></li>
    <li id="temp2"></li>
    <li id="temp3"></li>
    <li id="temp4"></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have implemented your suggested changes; no luck.

Comment: I've just inserted a code-snipped to better understand as what needs to be changed in order to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing brace for function showTime. Add a closing brace(}) before  `window.onload = showTime` and you are done!

And also, in for loop condition should be i <= 4 so that you can get temperature for all points.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parenthesis on the line

> window.onload = showTime

Try window.onload = showTime(); instead

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your script. See this update:

```
  <script>
    function showTime() {
        var tempByHour = new Array();
        tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
        tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
        tempByHour[2] = 63;
        tempByHour[3] = 65;
        tempByHour[4] = 62;

        for (var i = 0; i < tempByHour.length; i++) {
          var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
          var id = "temp" + i;
          var li = document.getElementById(id);

          if (i == 0) {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon is " + theTemp;
          } else {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + i + "was" + theTemp;
          }
        }
    }
    window.onload = showTime();
  </script>
```

This should fix your issue

Comment: I suppose , OP wants to display the whole content of the  `tempByHour` array. Which length is not not 3 but 4. And therefore the for loop condition needs to be amended to either `for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)` or `for (var i = 0; i < tempByHour.length; i++)`

Comment: apologies the array is of size 5 not 4. My bad! :]  But still your code above shows only 4 entries of the array.

Comment: You are right. Just noted that it has 5 items and not 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. `}` is missing.
2. You should include script after your `ul` tag. If you include script before initializing `ul` it will give you error as **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**
3. Your `for` loop should be like this `for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)` or you can take length of array. `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)` will not show last record.

Your code will be like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Temperature</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Temperature</h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="temp0"></li>
    <li id="temp1"></li>
    <li id="temp2"></li>
    <li id="temp3"></li>
    <li id="temp4"></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    function showTime() {
        var tempByHour = new Array();
        tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
        tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
        tempByHour[2] = 63;
        tempByHour[3] = 65;
        tempByHour[4] = 62;

        for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
          var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
          var id = "temp" + i;
          var li = document.getElementById(id);

          if (i == 0) {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon is " + theTemp;
          } else {
            li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + i + "was" + theTemp;
          }
        }
    }
        window.onload = showTime;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a } at the end of the for loop...

Here the code correct:

```
<script>
function showTime() {
    var tempByHour = new Array();
    tempByHour[0] = 59.2;
    tempByHour[1] = 60.1;
    tempByHour[2] = 63;
    tempByHour[3] = 65;
    tempByHour[4] = 62;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var theTemp = tempByHour[i];
      var id = "temp" + i;
      var li = document.getElementById(id);

      if (i == 0) {
        li.innerHTML = "The temperature at noon is " + theTemp;
      } else {
        li.innerHTML = "The temperature at " + i + "was" + theTemp;
      }
    }
}

    window.onload = showTime
```